# How my computer chooses a network if multiple networks are available

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ethernet, network-adapter

I have both **ethernet and WiFi**(from same ISP, with the same default gateway) connected to my computer. What medium the computer will choose to connect to the internet. What is the selection metric and process for both **windows and linux**

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Depends on your OS. What OS are you asking about?

Comment: @Spiff Both windows and linux as I need to use both.

Comment: Most programs will be following the normal rules of traffic handling, which will involve using the routing table.  You can see that with "netstat -nr" (in both Linux and Windows).  Your phrase of "selection metric" is really a good one, as a setting called "metric" may show up on the routing table (and be a part of the entire answer).  However, this is really only a partial answer, because the remaining unanswered piece is "how does the computer decide what to put into the routing table?"